# Sequelize Error: findAll is not a function

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js

I'm new to Sequelize and have been trying to query the model.
I got this error when i call the api:

```
Error fetching data: _database_models__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.brands.findAll is not a function
```

I also have this kind of error with create() when I use POST method

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank in advance

----------------------------------------------

this is route.ts file

```
import { create_brands, fetch_brands } from "../../../service/dbService";

export const POST = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const created_brands = await create_brands(req.body);
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(created_brands));
  } catch (err) {
    return new Response(`Error posting data: ${err.message}`, {
      status: 500,
    });
  }
};

export const GET = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const all_brands = await fetch_brands();
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(all_brands));
  } catch (err) {
    return new Response(`Error fetching data: ${err.message}`, {
      status: 500,
    });
  }
};
```

dbService.js

```
import { brands } from "../database/models";

console.log(JSON.stringify(brands));

export async function create_brands({ name }) {
  const createdBrand = await brands.create({
    name: name,
  });
  return createdBrand.dataValues;
}

export async function fetch_brands() {
  const allBrands = await brands.findAll();
  return allBrands;
}
```

models/brand.js

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
import connection from "../connection";

class brands extends Model {
  static associate(models) {
    brands.hasMany(models.products, {
      sourceKey: "id",
      foreignKey: "brandId",
      as: "products",
    });
  }
}

brands.init(
  {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    },
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  {
    sequelize: connection,
    modelName: "brands",
    timestamps: true,
    underscored: true,
  }
);

export default brands;
```

models/index.js

```
const sequelize = require("../connection");
const brands = require("./brands");
const products = require("./products");

export { sequelize, brands, products };
```

connection.js

```
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: "mysql",
  dialectModule: require("mysql2"),
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
});

async function testConnection() {
  try {
    await sequelize.authenticate();
    console.log("Connection has been established successfully.");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Unable to connect to the database:", error);
  }
}

testConnection();

module.exports = sequelize;
```

I tried to change importing and exporting brands model but it doesn't work

---

After editing all model files, I got this error

```
Error fetching data: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findAll')
```

I change the code in connection.js as below answer.

I will post my edited model code here.

brands.js

```
const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
class brands extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
    this.hasMany(models.products);
  }
}

brands.init(
  {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    },
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  {
    sequelize: connection,
    modelName: "brands",
    timestamps: true,
    underscored: true,
  }
);

return brands;
```

};

products.js

```
const { Model } = require("sequelize");

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class products extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      this.belongsTo(models.brands);
    }
  }
  products.init(
    {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      },
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
      images: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
      brandId: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        field: "brand_id",
        references: {
          model: brands,
          key: "id",
        },
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize: connection,
      modelName: "products",
      timestamps: true,
      underscored: true,
    }
  );

  return products;
};
```

For dbService.js, I didn't change anything.

Comment: Have you tried using `require` syntax instead of `import ... from`?

Answer (score 0):

`brands.findAll is not a function`

Here, **findAll** is the function that will be available to the brands if it is a valid Model. Based on the error, it seems that `brands` is not a valid model here. If we dive more into the model code.

//models/index.js

```
const sequelize = require("../connection");
const brands = require("./brands");
const products = require("./products");

export { sequelize, brands, products };
```

In this file, you are using CommonJS and ES6M together. Could you verify whether you can use import and export keyword in your nodejs project. I see this as the major problem for not identifying the `brands` as a model.

```
static associate(models) {
    brands.hasMany(models.products, {
      sourceKey: "id",
      foreignKey: "brandId",
      as: "products",
    });
  }
```

Additionally, there are other issues as well. You have defined the static method in the model brands called `associate`. But this method has not been called so far. so, the relation will never be established

To establish the relation with `products` model, you need to call the associate method passing the object containing the products model. Within the brands model file, it should be like this

```
const { products } = require('../database/models');
brands.associate({ products })
```

As you see inside the associate method, you are accessing the product model as `models.product`

Rather than doing this, there is a better of way of handling the models and their associations. You can create `models/index.js` with the following content

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../connection');

const basename = path.basename(__filename);

const db = {};
fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(
    (file) => file.indexOf('.') !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === '.js' && file.indexOf('.test.js') === -1
  )
  .forEach((file) => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model; // add model in db {}
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) { // associate method is called
    db[modelName].associate(db); // whole db {} passed to method
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

This file will load all the models within the model's directory and add them to the db object. It will also call the associate method of every model if available.

If you see the below code,

```
const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
```

It dynamically loads the models from each file making the function call and passing the `sequelize` and `DataTypes` as the parameters. so for this to work you need to make each model's file return function. Within the function,return value should be the model. So the brands model should be defined as follows:

models/brand.js

```
const { Model } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class brands extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      this.belongsTo(models.product);
    }
  }

  brands.init(
  {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    },
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  {
    sequelize: connection,
    modelName: "brands",
    timestamps: true,
    underscored: true,
  }
);

  return brands;
};
```

Same way should be continued for all other models as well.
Now, whenever the below code is called

```
require('../models');
```

This will first call the models/index.js file and make all the models available within the db object.

so,this is the valid code within the dbService

```
const { brands } = require('../database/models');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a detailed explanation. However, I tried to adjust the code as you suggested. I got this error instead "Error fetching data: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findAll')". Did i missed anything?

Comment: @Lavalse67 Sorry could not reply faster.
You can reference here: [Node-Sequelize](https://github.com/bsaal2/node-sequelize)